# Arranging Data in a matrix

Tags: matlab

I want to insert NaN between (X Y BetaTol ) and the next (X Y BetaTol )  and so on, so it seperates with an NaN column, the code I have is below which does not respshape it properly.

```
S={'X' 'Y' 'beta Tol'};  
T=repmat(S,1,7);        % to repeat character 7 times  
T=reshape([T, nan(size(T,1),2,size(T,3))], 1, {});  % trying to insert NaN in between the characters
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion would be to first reshape your Cell T to a matrix, so `nan` can be inserted at the end of each column. Then reshape it back to your original matrix shape.

```
T2=reshape(T,[],7);
T2(4,:)={nan};
T2=reshape(T2,1,[]);
```